# Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions.get_SerializerSettings()'

Tags: json.net, azure-web-app-service

Locally my project runs fine but when I deploy on Azure using a web app, I get the following error when it starts:

MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'.
SmartAdmin.Startup.<>c.b__13_7(MvcOptions options)

I've tried this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
                options.Filters.Add(new UserPreferencesLoaderAtrribute());
                var jsonFormatter = (JsonOutputFormatter)options.OutputFormatters.FirstOrDefault(f => f is JsonOutputFormatter);
                if (jsonFormatter != null)
                {
                jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            }
        });
```

And this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new UserPreferencesLoaderAtrribute());

        }).AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        });
```

Comment: Hey Jamie I am getting exactly the same issue on an azure app service since 2 August 2016 19:00 GMT. We are on beta 5 CLR. What version are you using? Did you manage to get a resolution.

Comment: I just had exactly the same error... now, and when I published yesterday it worked well. This could be a coincidence, but a recent change might have occurred on azure....

Comment: In my case, I discovered that the AddJsonOptions in startup.cs was involved in the exception:
 services
                services
                 .AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                });

Moreover, when I tried to publish on another existing appservice, it worked even if json option is set... There seem to have something broken or changed only on a specific appservice

Comment: Have you seen the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080363/missingmethodexception-with-newtonsoft-json-when-using-typenameassemblyformat-wi)? Makes sense to me.

Comment: We have exactly the same behavior works on one instance not on another instance.

Comment: This has started happening to me on one of my App Service deployments in the last day too. Duplicate deployment with duplicate build doesn't seem to have the problem.

Comment: for us, this app service 56 is working, 57 is broken

Azure App Service
57.0.8598.15 (rd_websites_stable.160801-1203)

Azure App Service
56.0.8598.48 (rd_websites_stable.160714-1252)

our app services work in west europe not in north, other people have working north systems

Comment: Are you using RC1, RC2 or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Note that this issue should no longer occur now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38851380/our-asp-net-core-rc1-application-stopped-working-and-then-started-working-again/38855259#38855259 for details.

Comment: Please see [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0a6bbaf-498a-4c1f-b869-6779ee18e04e/app-service-applications-may-experience-methodnotfound-exceptions-due-to-incorrect-newtonsoft-json?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for the latest update on this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I just worked all night and did eventually figured it out.  Here is what you need to do:

Make sure you install:
  -Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json version "6.0.0-rc1-final" 
   and 
   -Revert Netonsoft.Json to "6.0.6".

Then you can keep this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
```

project.json:

"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.6"

I had a bunch of trouble redeploying too but eventually this worked.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this did at least partially solve the problem I had. It's only a temporary solution though, getting off the release candidate version is a better solution.

Comment: Man you totally saved me with this, why those specific versions? Dunno but it works...

Comment: Saved my life! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just got off a call with Microsoft support as of yesterday (02 Aug 2016) Azure App Services now only support ASP.NET core, due to a breaking change:

A breaking change was released and anything other than ASP.NET core is not supported, so the only option is an upgrade. The breaking change is being rolled out to all (regions) eventually all your instances will fail.

Is ASP.NET 5, Core RC1, RC2 supported on Azure App Service? NO

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/06/14/supporting-asp-net-5-core-rc1-on-azure-app-service/

Verify your app is running the latest version of ASP.NET Core and not RC1 or RC2.

We were affected (North Europe) and upgraded our app from RC2 and it worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

We also saw this in production, contacted the team and got this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0a6bbaf-498a-4c1f-b869-6779ee18e04e/app-service-applications-may-experience-methodnotfound-exceptions-due-to-incorrect-newtonsoft-json?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

It appears that a fix for App Service is on its way as well. Meanwhile, the linked post contains pretty much the same instructions as the other answers here.