# Our ASP.NET core RC1 application stopped working and then started working again

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

We have built an .NET application on ASP.NET core RC1 (release candidate 1) and deployed it on Windows Azure in an Web App container. By August the 2'nd the application stopped working over night. We found out it was caused by the fact that Microsoft stopped supporting RC1 (and RC2 for that matter)  by that date.

The strange thing is that by today the application started working again without any change from our side.

Can anyone explain that behavior? I don't feel very comfortable with these kind of changes in the container environments.

NB: I should add that the error we saw in the log files was this one:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions.get_SerializerSettings()'
```

Comment: Is your web app container referring to Azure web app (PaaS) ?

Comment: maybe you should consider contacting azure support ...

Comment: There have been major changes in the two releases since RC1.  Among many other things, RC1 uses the dnx runtime which has been replaced with the dotnet CLI. Running down problems in completely obsolete code seems like a waste of time.

Comment: Though RC1 is indeed obsolete and should be avoided, there was a true issue at the root which could affect non-Core apps. See my Answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can explain what happened: a version of Json.NET v6.0.4 was mistakenly added to the GAC. Due to the way Json.NET is versioned, apps that had a different 6.x version in their bin folder ended up loading the one in the GAC. Your RC1 app probably has v6.0.7, and broke because v6.0.4 was missing APIs.

This assembly is not supposed to be in the GAC at all, so when we realized the issue, we removed it, which is when your app started working again. Apologies for the downtime.

That being said, you really should move away from RC1, which is not officially supported.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734195/method-not-found-newtonsoft-json-jsonserializersettings-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-m

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. We are working hard to make the migration but we appreciate that the site is working while we complete the upgrade.

Comment: Wow, "Sorry guys we just added an assembly to the GAC on our production servers" . That is quite astonishing.

Comment: I still have the same error! @DavidEbbo . Just since today. using Newtonsoft 9.0.1, in our RC1 app. Tried to upgrade to RC2 but failed due to packages not being compatible at that time.

Comment: We are getting the same issue @DavidEbbo and we have a really important demo tomorrow, anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Please see [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0a6bbaf-498a-4c1f-b869-6779ee18e04e/app-service-applications-may-experience-methodnotfound-exceptions-due-to-incorrect-newtonsoft-json?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for the latest update on this issue.